# laravel not wroking on hosting

Tags: laravel, hosting

Hello world i just completed developing laravel web in the localhost everything work fine but when i Booking hosting in webhostface.com i have tow  problem Error one is

```
file_put_contents(D:\web\API\storage\framework/sessions/r62WPTDKAhf5shlupWGhJzMv5U9BtEdzxrKYaGN5): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

and the problem tow is

```
Class 'Illuminate\View\Factory' not found
```

Knowing that I have made sure that all project files are up and there is no loss of files

Comment: delete every cache before deploy/upload on live server `php artisan optimize:clear` or `php artisan config:clear`, `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: Do I delete files and upload again  and before upload i do delete cache  ?

Comment: I've 2 questions. Did you copied and pasted whole laravel project to the server? Is the server working under the Linux OS ??

Comment: yes i do copy all file in the project to the serve ....yes the serve working on Linux OS

Comment: but in my locally i use windows OS